# How do I get the Active Sheet from an On Change event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Did a search on this site for "INSERT_ROW getActiveSheet" and found one hit: [Google Script: How can I run a script only when someone adds new rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258098/google-script-how-can-i-run-a-script-only-when-someone-adds-new-rows/20262665#20262665).  The accepted answer shows this code:

```
function myFunction(e){
  Logger.log(e.changeType);
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
    // do Something
    Browser.msgBox('New row(s) added');
  }
}
```

which is fine.  The problem I am having is in the "// do something" part of the code, what I want to do is get the Active Sheet and ultimately the Active Range so that I can add formulas to the new rows programmatically when a user inserts new rows.  I have tried both:

```
e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
```

and

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()
```

to attempt to get the name of the Active Sheet, but it keeps returning the first sheet in the spreadsheet and the range A1.

When I run this code:

```
Browser.msgBox(Utilities.jsonStringify(e));
```

it does not return the active sheet, only the authMode, changeType and user properties, as it shows it should in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events).

There must be a way, however, to find out what has been changed, otherwise what is the point of an onChange event?

Comment: As an aside, I've been reading quite a bit about the proper forming of questions on SO, and I'm wondering if this one is well formed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem was [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3926), which is now fixed.